# Перегрузка индексатора статического класса

Tags: c#

Хотелось бы в своей программе на C# создать класс, к которому можно обратиться по типу `ClassName[i]`, т.е. указать имя этого класса и сразу индекс нужного элемента в нем. При этом нужно заметить, что сам класс является статическим. Я пробовал `this[int index]` но, как я понял, оно реализуется только в объектах класса. Есть ли выход?

Comment: Статический класс может существовать только в единственном экземпляре, посему его невозможно "перечислять".

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/401232/6766879

Comment: @Bulson, ну почему же, пусть у вас класс не статический и вы создали всего один единственный экземпляр. Он нормально справляется с индексатором, хоть экземпляр всего и один, но он может содержать внутри некую коллекцию элементов других классов.

Comment: @АндрейNOP если один класс содержит внутри коллекцию элементов др.класса, то в таком случае я согласен. Я то понял вопрос так, что необходимо перечислять экземпляры того же класса.

Comment: @Bulson У меня класс внутри содержит приватный список (`List`), к которому я хотел обеспечить `get` доступ непосредственно через индексатор.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, в текущей версии языка (C# 7.2) статические индексаторы не поддерживаются (как и некоторые другие вещи, такие как, параметризированные свойства, которые есть в IL).

Вместо этого вы всегда можете воспользоваться методом с параметром (парой методов) или свойством, возвращающим тип, который уже имеет индексатор. Да, в коде это будет выглядеть чуть-чуть длиннее, чем могло быть.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.